# How to consume messages from Azure EventHub topic from command line?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am new to azure eventhub, i know that we can consume data from kafka topic and particular consumer group using below CLI command of

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic <topic_name> -group <group_name>
```

Is there a similar way we can consume data from azure eventhub topic through CLI. I have gone through this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quickstart-cli), the document i having CLI commands to create eventhub name space and eventhub topics but not to consume. Please help how can i consume messages from azure eventhub through CLI

Comment: Is your Event Hub Kafka-enabled? If so, you might even be able to use your kafka cli (I havent tried that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Kafka CLI commands for consuming events from Azure Event Hubs topics as well. Please check the sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/tree/master/quickstart/kafka-cli).

Comment: Hi! There is any way to view/tail this events in azure cli without kafka cli extension?